# PRNG in iOS KeyChain

Tags: ios, security, random, keychain

My boss is asking me, which PRGN (Pseudo Random Number Generator) is using our iOS App for encrypting and decrypting data.

We are using the native KeyChain services for storing the data and I don't know what to answer since we are using the KeyChainItemWrapper for accessing the single items i.e. password, ports, etc. in our App and there is not too much reference about this.

I already debugged the app to see if I find something but I couldn't find something yet.

Any help would be appreciated,
thanks

Comment: `arc4random` is the go-to generator on OS-X.  I haven't found any documentation saying that's what's used in KeyChain, but I'd bet on it.  Check out its `man` page.  By the way, it's PRNG, not PRGN.

Answer (score 0):

If you need random bytes as opposed to a a random number:

`randomBytes:` returns count random bytes in *bytes, allocated by the caller.
Returns 0 on success or -1 if something went wrong, check `errno` to find out the real error.

```
#import <Security/Security.h> 

+ (NSData *)randomBytes:(size_t)count
{
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:count];
    SecRandomCopyBytes( kSecRandomDefault,
                        data.length,
                        data.mutableBytes);
    return data;
}
```

Be sure to add the Security framework.